# How to integrate Opencvblobslib library with OpenCV with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, blob

I am trying to calculate the area of a certain region of an image using the concept of SURF (Speeded-Up Robust Features). But when I try to  use a function such as contourArea, I get an exception. What are the possible steps that I should follow to install the specific blob libraries to calculate the area? (I am using OpenCV in Visual Studio). Any other method to caclculate the area using blobs?